# Changing the colors inside of Netbeans programatically?

Tags: netbeans, ide, config

So I came up today with an idea of having a java program that runs in the background on my PC and periodically checks the system time, and when I notice a change in the seasons ( Winter, Fall, Summer, Spring), I would change all the colors of the IDE (the keywords and comments and background) to fit with the colors of the season. Unfortunately, I can't find where this information is stored on file. Does anyone have any idea where it could be or if this is possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes it is possible !!!

1. Run time options
2. Using configuration file
3. Using netbeans libraries

#### 1. Run time options

If you like to have 'MetalLookAndFeel & fontsize 14, run below command

```
netbeans --laf javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel --fontsize 14
```

You can install list of themes from this link → [Netbeans themes](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/). You can launch a different theme programmatically based upon your choice.

#### 2. Using configuration file

This can be achieved by updating the `netbeans.conf` file located in below location `${nb-install}/etc/netbeans.conf`
for ex:

> C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1\etc\netbeans.conf

Update the conf file with desired theme & font size programmatically. 
for ex:

> netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m
>    -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"

You can update multiple look and feel options

- Windows - com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel
- Metal - javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel
- GTK - com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel
- Aqua - apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel

Additionally, you can configure other parameters as well. 
All startup parameters listed here → [Startup Parameters](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqStartupParameters)

#### 3. Using netbeans libraries

You might be more interested in this. 
Full netbeans API → [netbeans Api](http://bits.netbeans.org/8.0/javadoc/) 
Corresponding Jar files → [jar files](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgnetbeansmoduleseditorsettingsjar.htm)

```
`org.netbeans.api.editor.settings.FontColorSettings` will be used to change the font settings which include keywords, syntax, background, foreground etc.
```

One small example for your reference

```
public void updateColors() {
    EditorUI editorUI = Utilities.getEditorUI(textComponent);
    if (editorUI == null) {
        return;
    }
    String mimeType = NbEditorUtilities.getMimeType(textComponent);
    FontColorSettings fontColorSettings = MimeLookup.getLookup(MimePath.get(mimeType)).lookup(FontColorSettings.class);
    Coloring lineColoring = Coloring.fromAttributeSet(fontColorSettings.getFontColors(FontColorNames.LINE_NUMBER_COLORING));
    Coloring defaultColoring = Coloring.fromAttributeSet(fontColorSettings.getFontColors(FontColorNames.DEFAULT_COLORING));

    if (lineColoring == null) {
        return;
    }

    // use the same color as GlyphGutter
    final Color backColor = lineColoring.getBackColor();
    // set to white by o.n.swing.plaf/src/org/netbeans/swing/plaf/aqua/AquaLFCustoms
    if (org.openide.util.Utilities.isMac()) {
        backgroundColor = backColor;
    } else {
        backgroundColor = UIManager.getColor("NbEditorGlyphGutter.background"); //NOI18N
    }
    if (null == backgroundColor) {
        if (backColor != null) {
            backgroundColor = backColor;
        } else {
            backgroundColor = defaultColoring.getBackColor();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I tried importing the package for the Netbeans API that you suggested but it clearly isn't there by default. I checked online for a download but couldn't find it. Any idea how I add it? Is it in Netbeans somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: Jar files download link → http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgnetbeansmoduleseditorsettingsjar.htm , I have updated my answer as well for future reference.